# Login Failure: Failed to open the explicitly specified database

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, initialization, dbcontext

I have created am MVC4 project with EF and have just tried to create a seed for the database tables which have now been successfully created. I have created an initialiser class as follows:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        var companies = new List<Company>
        {
            new Company { CompanyID = 1, CompanyName = "eBay", LogoURL = "~/Images/test1.jpg" },
            new Company { CompanyID = 2, CompanyName = "Coca Cola", LogoURL = "~/Images/test2.jpg" },
            new Company { CompanyID = 3, CompanyName = "Google", LogoURL = "~/Images/test3.jpg" },
            new Company { CompanyID = 4, CompanyName = "Microsoft", LogoURL = "~/Images/test.jpg" }
        };
        companies.ForEach(c => context.Company.Add(c));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Inside my Context class I have the following:

```
public MyContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
        this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        this.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
```

The database is being successfully created but the data is not being input into the Company table as I had expected. I have looked at the event logs an I am getting the following messages:

**INFO :** Login failed for user DOMAIN\username'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.x.xx]

**INFO :** Starting up database 'dbname'

The login seems to fail 2 seconds before the database 'starts up'. Would this be the cause of the non population of the company table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.